# display "movie name" instead of "movie id" as recommendation from apache mahout

Tags: mahout, mahout-recommender

I am developing a simple movie recommender system using apache mahout by referring a short video here- https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=yD40rVKUwPI. The code for recommender is

```
    public class App 
 {
    public static  List<RecommendedItem> getRecommend(int k) throws Exception
   {
            ClassLoader classLoader = App.class.getClassLoader();

            DataModel model = new FileDataModel(new    File(classLoader.getResource("data/dataset.csv").getFile()));
        UserSimilarity similarity = new PearsonCorrelationSimilarity(model);
        UserNeighborhood neighborhood = new ThresholdUserNeighborhood(0.1, similarity, model);
        UserBasedRecommender recommender = new     GenericUserBasedRecommender(model, neighborhood, similarity);
        List<RecommendedItem> recommendations = recommender.recommend(k, 3);
        return recommendations;
     }
}
```

[image]

This generates recommendations in the form of movie id's.What I want is to display names instead of movie id. The dataset I am using (which generates id's)has following columns in csv form

```
user_id   movie_id  rating
```

but since there is a MovieLens dataset which has two files- one with fields

```
   user_id   movie_id  rating
```

and second with

```
  movie_id   movie_name
```

How can i use the above resourcesto get movie_names instead of id. Is it possible with DataModel class or there is some other way out.
  I want recommendations as

```
movie_name  value
```

instead of present

```
movie_id  value
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You likely cannot with Mahout alone. You will need to load the movie title CSV file using a CSV reader, or import it into a database, and map movie IDs back to names yourself.

Comment: yes I do have a movie_title.csv also apart from a rating.csv. What I was thinking was to merge these two files anyhow into single csv and then use that as a dataset instead of my present dataset(rating.csv). Will it work? Please elaborate a bit, I am trying it for the first time . rating.csv contains only movie_id whereas movie_title.csv maps movie_id with title.

Comment: I do not know enough about Mahout's API and data model to know if it will let you model the data in that way. I doubt it, but could very well be wrong. A lot of these systems use a rating matrix, and you need to look up item metadata yourself.